# Can't use Optimization functions with ilnumerics in c#

Tags: c#, optimization, ilnumerics

If I am right, there is a optimization toolbox in ilnumerics. After I successfully installed ilnumerics in my project I tried to write some examples from http://ilnumerics.net/media/ILNumericsOptimizationToolboxDocumentation.pdf in it. However anytime i use *** = Optimization.*** there is an error, like "Optimization" is an undefinded variable. "The name 'Optimization' does not exist in the current context"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ILNumerics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

class Program : ILMath
{
    public static ILRetArray<double> MeyerFunc(ILInArray<double> x, ILInArray<double> t)
    {
        using (ILScope.Enter(x, t))
        {
            return x[0] * exp(x[1] / (t + x[2]));
        }
    }
    //The computation of the minimum is done as follows: 
    // Minimum computation: 
    ILArray<double> t = linspace<double>(0, 15, 16).T;
    ILArray<double> ydata = array<double>(34780.0, 28610.0, 23650.0, 19630.0, 16370.0,
     13720.0, 11540.0, 9744.0, 8261.0, 7030.0,
    6005.0, 5147.0, 4427.0, 3820.0, 3307.0, 2872.0);

    ILArray<double> x0 = array<double>(1.0, 200.0, 100.0);

    Func<ILInArray<double>, ILRetArray<double>> meyerfunction = x =>
    {
        using (ILScope.Enter(x))
        {
            return MeyerFunc(x, t);
        }
    };

    ILArray<double> xm = Optimization.optimpdl(meyerfunction, x0, ydata);
    }
}
```

Comment: `there is an error, like` Paste the *full* exception exactly as it appears. Also indicate the line number that it is occurring on.

Comment: I also see the line `ILArray<double> xopt` appears *outside* of the `Main` function. Are you sure that's supposed to be there? Is `Optimization` supposed to be a static class? If so, then you probably haven't included the correct namespace so that it is defined and accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
ILArray<double> xopt = Optimization.optimpdl(objfunc, zeros<double>(2, 1));
```

is supposed to be inside the main function, not after and outside of it.